# Tight bound for integrable functions on bounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I have integrals of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\{\psi_k(x)\}^pf(x)dx$ where $\psi_k(x)=x$ if $|x|\leq k$, $\psi_k(x)=\text{sign}(x)k$ otherwise, $f(x)$ is a probability density function (so a nonnegative function), $p$ an integer greater than 1, and $k$ some positive real number. In general, the integral can be broken down into three parts $\{-k\}^p\int_{-\infty}^{-k}f(x)dx + \int_{-k}^{k}x^pf(x)dx + k^p\int_{k}^{\infty}f(x)dx$. Now, suppose that I let $k$ tend to 0 at some arbitrary rate. The terms on the sides are easy to deal with because either $\int_{-\infty}^{-k}f(x)dx$ or $\int_{k}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ are bounded, i.e., $O(1)$, so that the terms on the sides are both $o(k^p)$. I was wondering whether it is possible to obtain a tight bound for the integral on the middle, a bound possibly tighter than the one obtainable from the inequality $|\int_{-k}^k x^p f(x) dx|\leq \int_{-k}^k |x^p f(x)| dx=2Ck=o(k)$, for some $C>0$. The problem with the latter bound lies in the fact that $C$ is "too vague" for my purposes, the ideal would be to obtain a bound not linear in $k$ and that does not depend on a tuning constant that can be anything, e.g., $C$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left|\int_{-k}^k x^pf(x)dx\right|\leq \left|\int_{-k}^0 x^pf(x)dx\right|+\left|\int_{0}^k x^pf(x)dx\right|
\end{align}
Furthermore:
\begin{align}\left|\int_0^k x^pf(x)dx\right|&\leq\left|\int_0^k k^pf(x)dx\right|\\
&\leq k^p \left|\int_0^k f(x)dx\right|\\
&\leq k^p
\end{align}
Same argument applies to $\left|\int_{-k}^0 x^pf(x)dx\right|$ hence you have $\left|\int_{-k}^k x^pf(x)dx\right|$ is $o(k^p)$

Comment: wonderful, thanks!